# Fix a css/jquery animate issue on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, jquery-animate, css-position

Here is the web site: plantcatching.com

Set "Montreal" in the search textbox and hit Enter. The map should go there and show results (after you zoom in one notch I think). A panel will slide from the left for the list of results. This panel has a white arrow attached so that it's possible to collapse/expand it. Here is what happens:

- On **IE/Firefox**: the panel slides well.
- On **Chrome**: the first time the panel extends, it works well. Then any
  new manipulation shows the issue. The content of the panel and the
  tabs will change position only after the jquery.animate("left") is
  finished.

I let you have a look at the css structure under firebug or other dev bar, but basically it seems that chrome doesn't like the various "position:relative" css rules inside the panel. The problem is that I don't control them. They are set by the [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) jquery plugin. To check that this is the actual reason, just zoom out a little until a small window appears notifying that you should zoom in again. This empties the content of the pane and collapses it. See how it closes nicely this time, since there is no content anymore in the pane.

**The question is**: how should I modify the css (the part I control) so that it works well in Chrome and continues to work well in other browsers?

Let me know if something is unclear, I will update this question.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There was no answer here, so I decided to fix it myself by adopting css3 transitions on chrome only. This is now far better but you will notice that the tabs are a bit lagging when the panel slides. This does not happen in non webkit browsers.